# API.ai contexts do not seem to exist in LUIS

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

My team is more experienced with API.ai and only starting to learn LUIS.

We are used to having contexts which is groups of intents which are matched on a user's input and selected among.

In API.ai, the navigation moves from one intent to another, looking at the output context of the current intent and attempting to match among those  intents **only**.

It does not seem that LUIS has that context notion. What strategies should I use so I wont need it as build bots in LUIS? Or is there something like contexts which I should be using?

Comment: What is the problem with just dropping the context and use all of the intents and maybe do the context in the application logic? LUIS has domains which are working in a similar way, but they are prebuilt :/

Answer (score 2):

If by context, you want LUIS to match an utterance to different intents depending on the previous answer, you can use different LUIS apps or models. I could be wrong but, from what I can see API.ai's context is just a model within a model.

You do have to add the logic in your application to store the context as Steven G. said but you could simply have a top level LUIS app and 1 ore more contextual LUIS apps. Then select the endpoint to send the utterance to based on: if you have a context and what the context is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the BotBuilder SDK then you create `Dialog` classes and essentially your dialog exists on rails, so given a user's input you move to the next turn in the dialog. This doesn't need LUIS, because you've already declared all the actions your bot should do.

It is possible to create a pattern that constantly does LUIS calls, but you'll need to add the logic into your code so that it looks for a specific intent from a group of intents before proceeding.

As Miskov indicates, LUIS context handling is actually handled in your application. [Prebuilt domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-use-prebuilt-domains) however, are *also* context ignorant. They're a simply template of intents and entities with labeled utterances.

C# BotBuilder SDK + LUIS: [Example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-LUIS)

Node.js BotBuilder SDK + LUIS: [Example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS)